# Linq dynamic Sum

Tags: entity-framework, sum

I want to send a sum after I have collected multiple fields in the database.
But I need to write the fields as string.
I may not be able to fully explain my problem, I will try to exemplify it.

What I want to do is this code's lambda state

**I want to do :**

```
expression = x => x.M1_TotalLoss + x.M2_TotalLoss;
```

**My Code :**

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(FooDomain), "x");
var value = Expression.Property(param, ("M1_TotalLoss"+"M2_TotalLoss"));

var rest = Expression.Lambda<Func<FooDomain, double>>(value, param);

var result = myContext.FooDomain().
                GroupBy(gp=>gp.Year).
                Select(s => new
                {
                    TotalLoss = Math.Round(s.AsQueryable().Sum(rest), 2)
                }).
                OrderByDescending(o => o.TotalLoss).
                ToList();
```

But since I can not write the predicate correctly, I get the following error:

exceptionMessage= Example feature 'M1_TotalLossM2_TotalLoss' not defined for type 'FooDomain'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let see what we have here:

```
x => x.M1_TotalLoss + x.M2_TotalLoss
```

`x` apparently is a *parameter*, so

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(FooDomain), "x");
```

is ok.

`x.M1_TotalLoss` and `x.M2_TotalLoss` are *properties* of the *parameter* `x` called respectively `"M1_TotalLoss"` and `"M2_TotalLoss"`, so let reflect that:

```
var value1 = Expression.Property(param, "M1_TotalLoss");
var value2 = Expression.Property(param, "M2_TotalLoss");
```

and `x.M1_TotalLoss + x.M2_TotalLoss` is just the *add* operation of the two:

```
var value = Expression.Add(value1, value2);
```

and you are done - the rest of the code is ok.

What about more than 2 properties?

Since `op1 + op2 + op3` is equivalent of `(op1 + op2) + op3`, or with method notation `Add(Add(op1, op2), op3)`, it can be seen that N additions can be described recursively as adding the next operand to the result of the addition of the previous operands. Which can easily be implemented with LINQ `Aggregate` method.

So given `IEnumerable<string>` containing the desired property names, you can use something like this:

```
var propertyNames = new [] { "M1_TotalLoss", "M2_TotalLoss", };

var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(FooDomain), "x");
var value = propertyNames.Select(name => Expression.Property(param, name))
    .Aggregate<Expression>(Expression.Add);

// the rest of the code (same as yours)
```

Comment: Actually it was a simple question.I didn't see expression.add
I've come to answer my question then i saw your answer I did as you anser. Thanks a lot